# WPF Accessing DataSet within DataContext in MVVM project. How do I do that?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dataset

I have a feeling this is going to be something stupid I am missing.  This is my first attempt at Creating a SQL Server database and connecting to it using C# and WPF.

I have a View and the **DataContext** is the **ViewModel**.  Within the **ViewModel**, I have a **dataset** of **PatientData.Patients**.

If I set the View **DataContext** to **PatientData.Patient**, the fields in a Grid show the Patient data but then my bound CONTROLS (Next/Prev/First/Last) do not work.  If I set the **DataContext** to the **ViewModel**, my bound controls work but the **DATASET** does not.

I believe I need to set the Grid containing the Patients bound control's **DataContext** to **PatientData.Patient** BUT I can't figure out how.

So I set the View **DataContext** to the **ViewModel** all my controls work, now how do I reference the **PatientData.Patients** dataset that is part of the **ViewModel**?

This is the class of the Patient

```
public class PatientRecord
{
    public int PatientID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string LastFirstName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string FirstLastName { get; set; }
    public string Addr1 { get; set; }
    public string Addr2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public string Race { get; set; }
    public bool HealthIns { get; set; }
    public bool OutsidePCP { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryCareProvider { get; set; }
    public object Modified { get; set; }
}
```

I have a dataset that I pull the data from called Patients that matches the Patient record so I can read the data into the record.  In the Constructor for the patient edit screen I pass in the Patients records an the currently selected Patient.  I want to be able to edit the current record and then move around to other records

```
    public PatientMaintenanceViewModel( ObservableCollection<PatientRecord> patients, PatientRecord selectedPatient )
    {
        try
        {
            Patients = patients;
            SelectedPatient = selectedPatient;
            taPatients.Fill( dsPatient.Patients );
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            MessageBox.Show( ex.Message, "PatientMaintenanceViewModel" );
            var errors = dsPatient.Patients.GetErrors();
        }
        taManager.PatientsTableAdapter = taPatients;

        //          DataContext = PatientData.Patient;
        View = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView( dsPatient.Patients );
        MaritalStatuses = _patientRepo.GetMaritalStatuses();
        Races = _patientRepo.GetRaces();
    }
```

![Patient Edit Screen][1]

So am I approaching this wrong or am I going down the right path but have my code screwed up?

I have the dataset data of Patients and the ObservableCollection of Patients that I carry around in the code.

Comment: Could you please share your code

Comment: The way we handle database at work is we have a server we query for data and so we have to carry around the data in structures and SET and GET data from the database.  I get this feeling with Datasets you just use the data in it's stucture without having to duplicate the structure in outside structures.  Is this correct

Comment: Is your viewmodel is PatientData or PatientData is member of your ViewModel?

Comment: PatientData is just in the "Code-Behind"

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean, but you should set the DataContext of the View to the ViewModel. And for the Grid, set its ItemsSource property to Patients. Shouldn't that be enough?